# https for nodejs with Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, ssl

I am using 443 for port apache. I had add certificate as well. Apache is listing port 443.
My node server is listening port 8124

Under appp.js file i added this code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/mykey.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/mykey.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mynextbiggasomefilename.crt')
};
```

and

```
var app = require('https').createServer(options);
app.listen(8124);
```

Ajax with https request is not working. Any Suggestions
Thanks

Comment: So client->apache is HTTPS. How are you proxying through to node? Have you set up your proxy logic to also use HTTPS? My guess would be the proxy connection is trying to use HTTP. Do you need to use HTTPS for the internal connection?

Comment: yes i need https. How to set proxy logic

Comment: is it giving CORS issue?

Comment: is it appache server sending https post request to nodejs server?

Comment: yes Apache is sending http request to node server .. i also tried with https . not working in both of cases